# Verify employee name

Tags: excel, automation, power-automate

I am getting into Power Automate Desktop lately and would like to apply it in the company I work for. Specifically the system we use for creating support tickets (on behalf of employees).

I have pulled down the "DisplayNames" from AD of all the employees we are expected to help.

The ticket system will however create a ticket in **MY** name if an incorrectly spelled name is entered on the website front-end. The same goes for any colleagues who may use the flow I am writing... they will be falsely regarded as the ticket reporter.

The Power Automate flow loops through the items in the column for employee names, opens the webpage, fills out the relevant text fields (such as subject, problem description etc) and then submits the ticket. Normally the affected employee does this, but from time to time there are large projects where we must do the data entry (so that the project can be evenly split between the team).

I would like to have a means of checking the employee names are all valid before any tickets are submitted (whilst still in Excel).

Here is what I have done so far... a macro.

```
Sub checkCells()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Range("A2:A1000")

For Each myCell In myRange

If myCell Like "Mr Jones" Then
myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
End If


If myCell Like "Mr Murphy" Then
myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
End If

If myCell Like "Mr T" Then
myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
End If


Next myCell

End Sub
```

This works but it doesn't scale very well. There are over 1000 employees. Even the 3 examples listed here, involved writing "concatenate" functions on another worksheet. Messy.

Can anybody help me write an easier section of code?

It would be great too to have a means of flagging any incorrect names in red.

Thanks!

Regards,

William

Comment: How are support tickets being submitted? A form? If so, can't you cross check the submission against an Excel Table or some AD, and then get a condition on how to handle next following the submission? VBA doesn't seem like the right approach for PowerApps, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, it's a web based form. The VBA is only intended for making sure the names in each row of the 'user' column are indeed correct. Power Automate Handles the actual data entry.

Comment: Something else I should add is that the XL file is normally closed while Power Automate is doing its thing. VBA otherwise plays no role in the ticket submission. The purpose of the question is to see how I make sure that the data for each user is 'clean' before the Power Automate Desktop flow is executed.

Comment: yea, I get it. The file can remain closed, and you can append the Form Entry to a table that checks with a basic Match Formula if it's a valid entry. You can then use PowerApps to evaluate a corresponding column in the new row (that has the match function).  I can detail out an answer maybe later tonight. Sort of hard to explain with Powerapps since it's not clean code.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I *may* have a found a solution that should work for the time being...

It obviously needs to be extended with more users, but that's not really big deal using the CONCATENATE function, in this particular case.

The cherry on top though would be to have the range stop where the the last name entry in column A sits. It extending on for (what looks like) infinity may put users off.

Thanks.

```
Sub checkUserNamesForTicket()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Range("A2:A1000")
For Each myCell In myRange
If myCell Like "Mr Jones" Or _
myCell Like "Mr Smith" Or _
myCell Like "Mr Murphy" Then

myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)

Else: myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 0)


End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: The code for changing the colour of the cell when the employee name appears to be invalid has been found. Thanks for everbody's help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to PowerApps myself, so I spent some time tinkering around with this. There's several ways to handle this, but below are two options that leverage PowerApps connected to Excel instead of VBA. You will have to use [Excel Tables](https://exceljet.net/excel-tables), but this is far easier than using VBA.

To begin, it's important that you have a flow triggered by a form submission that captures the inputs. I built [a sample form here](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Gd7ERvwPVEyqhu5ydK-p16CYbVwW34FPlcQd5S6vxcRUM0dLMUFYNVozUktETVVRSUFHNVlDS0hDMS4u) (feel free to have fun with it).

You must create a flow that's triggered when a submission is received. This should be pretty straightforward, but here's some screenshots I used based on the form I lined that's id is: `Example Condition With PowerApps`.

[image: Create a new flow]

[image]

[image]

At this point you will have dynamic content that includes the responses from the form submission and you can do a variety of checks/tasks with this.

[image]

### Option 1 Test For Match

You can use some error checking to see if the `Your UserName` text matches any rows in a table in excel. Let's presume you have a table that you've populated a table with all valid names from your AD and given it a table name of `directoryTable` (i.e. something like below) and an excel file called `SamplePowerApps.xlsx`.

[image]

You can then test if the user's entry matches any values. To avoid caps issue, I created a function in the table to turn all values to upper case, as well as modified the search text of the user's entry to be upper case. You can run the test by using the [Excel Connector object Get a Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#get-a-row) which will look like this for our example:

[image]

The key value is a combination of the response user name, but turning characters to upper case:
[image]

This will result in either a successful row being found (which we will do nothing with), or it will thrown an error. To test for that we need to create two next steps that would run based on success or no success. Because this post is getting rather long, I'll spare you the details, but this step is documented well [in this article](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-handling/).

## Option 2 Use Excel Formulas To Test (probably easier)

This is similar to above, but rather than getting a row in a table, [we will add a row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#add-a-row-into-a-table). In the below example, I will be adding a row to a table called `responseTable`. This same table will have a column that tests if the username is valid by doing a lookup to the same AD list (my exact formula is `=ISNUMBER(MATCH([@UserName],directoryTable[USERID],0))`. With a rule setup like shown below, you would get a table that you can sort on `ValidUser` column showing True or False for valid user.

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for that. I have used the cloud-based version of Power Automate for some tasks in the past - i.e mail merge functionality that the desktop version of Excel and/or Word cannot (or will not) allow for. For this particular job though, I will have to stick with the 'Desktop" version of Power Automate.

Comment: I'm not as famaliar with the desktop version. Did you get your VBA solution needed?

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking! Yes, in the end I did. The best solution was to write a macro, declare an array and then add the employee names to it. When the macro is executed it checks the values of the cells in a particular range to see if they are in array or not. Work perfectly. No need to worry about tickets being created under the wrong name! Power Automate Desktop is a breeze to 'program' but one has to sacrifice a lot speed - it takes it a few seconds for it to check each row of the XL file and see if a ticket URL already exists. I may need to use Python when the list gets longer.